# Case statements: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
id  date    value
------------------
1   1        null
1   2        a
1   3        b
1   4        null
2   1        null
2   2        null
2   3        null
2   4        null
2   5        null
```

If value is null in all id's then max of date of that id and if we have value then max of date with value id.

Required output is:

```
id  date    value
-----------------
1   3           b
2   5        null
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) - not a statement ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical method for this type of problem is `row_number()`.  You can create a CASE expression to define a priority:

```
select id,
    date,
    value
from (
    select id,
        date,
        value,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by case when value is not null then 1 else 2 end asc, date desc) rn
    from UnnamedTable
    ) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/JAOI59432)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT id, 
           [date], 
           [value], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [value] DESC, [date] DESC) as rn
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```